# MVC3 Bind Model to jquery DataTables plugin on ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm aware of a few ways to handle what I'm trying to do, but I'm I'd like to use the best way. Best being least custom/least code solution.  I've got a table on my view and I'm using the JQuery [DataTables plugin](http://datatables.net/).  I'm using the plugin's feature that allows it to fetch JSON formatted data from the server.  When the plugin makes the ajax call to my Action on my controller, it adds a lot of info to the request that I can bind to a model.  However, I can't control the keys in the request, so I end up with properties on my model like, 'sSearch_1', 'bSearchable_1', 'bSortable_2', etc...

So, my Action Method looks like this...

```
    public JsonResult CompanyList(JQueryDataTableParamModel param){
        var allCompanies = DataRepository.GetCompanies();
        IEnumerable<Company> filteredCompanies;
        //Check whether the companies should be filtered by keyword
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch))
        {
            //Optionally check whether the columns are searchable at all 
            var isNameSearchable = param.bSearchable_1; // Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSearchable_1"]);
            var isAddressSearchable = param.bSearchable_2; // Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSearchable_2"]);
            var isTownSearchable = param.bSearchable_3; //Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSearchable_3"]);

            filteredCompanies = DataRepository.GetCompanies()
               .Where(c => isNameSearchable && c.Name.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
                           ||
                           isAddressSearchable && c.Address.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
                           ||
                           isTownSearchable && c.Town.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            filteredCompanies = allCompanies.ToList();
        }

        var isNameSortable = param.bSortable_1; 
        var isAddressSortable = param.bSortable_2; 
        var isTownSortable = param.bSortable_3; 
        var sortColumnIndex = param.iSortCol_0;  
        Func<Company, string> orderingFunction = (c => sortColumnIndex == 1 && isNameSortable ? c.Name :
                                                       sortColumnIndex == 2 && isAddressSortable ? c.Address :
                                                       sortColumnIndex == 3 && isTownSortable ? c.Town :
                                                       "");

        //var sortDirection = Request["sSortDir_0"]; // asc or desc
        filteredCompanies = param.sSortDir_0 == "asc" ? filteredCompanies.OrderBy(orderingFunction).ToList() : filteredCompanies.OrderByDescending(orderingFunction).ToList();

        var displayedCompanies = filteredCompanies.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength);
        var result = from c in displayedCompanies select new[] { Convert.ToString(c.ID), c.Name, c.Address, c.Town };
        return Json(new
                        {   param.sEcho,
                            iTotalRecords = allCompanies.Count(),
                            iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredCompanies.Count(),
                            aaData = result
                        },
                    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult Detail() {
        return View();
    }

}
```

As you can see in this example, I've got a few places where I've pulled the value from the Model, and set it to a variable of the same type, but with a more meaningful name.  While this makes my code more readable, it's redundant.  For example:

```
var isNameSearchable = param.bSearchable_1;
```

What I would like to do, is create a property on my Model 'IsNameSearchable' and have it bind to the 'bSearchable_1'.

I've come up with these options:
1. I know I can create a custom Model binder that implements IModelBinder, but then I would have to do the complete model binding, and there is a lot of the default model binding that will still work for what I want to do.
2. I could inherit from the DefaultModelBinder, and only override the binding I need to override, and allow the default binding to work as normal in most cases.
3. Leave it they way I have it, auto-binding my model to meaningless values and manually binding to meaningful variables later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with option number 2:

> I could inherit from the DefaultModelBinder, and only override the
>   binding I need to override, and allow the default binding to work as
>   normal in most cases.